# Make 1 dimensional array 2D using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of numbers which I wish to add a second column such that the array becomes 2D like in the example below:

```
    a = [1,1,1,1,1]
    b = [2,2,2,2,2]
```

should become:

```
    c = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
```

I am not sure how to do this using numpy?

Comment: ``zip`` should do the job, ``[[x,y] for x, y in zip(a,b)]``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just stack them and then transpose the resulting array with `.T`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
b = np.array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])

c = np.stack((a, b)).T
```

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy built-in functions:

```
import numpy as np
c = np.vstack((np.array(a),np.array(b))).T.tolist()
```

`np.vstack` stacks arrays vertically. `.T` transposes the array and `tolist()` converts it back to a list.

Another similar way to do it, is to add a dimensions using `[:,None]` and then you can horizontally stack them without the need to transpose:

```
c = np.hstack((np.array(a)[:,None],np.array(b)[:,None])).tolist())
```

output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```